# Entity Framework without a DB?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4, entity

Is it possible to use Entity Framework 4.3 without linking the model to an actual DB in the back-end?

I need to build a conceptual model of a database in the VS designer and then I'd like to manually handle fetches, inserts and updates to various back-end databases (horrible legacy systems).  I need to be able to do this without EF moaning about not having tables mapped, etc.  I realise that this is a very odd thing to want to do...

The reason for this is that we would like to move from these legacy systems into a well designed data model and .NET environment, but we need to still maintain functionality and backward compatibility with the old systems during development. We will then reach a stage where we can import the old data (coming from about 6 different databases) into a single DB that matches the EF model I'm building. In theory, we should then be able to switch over from the hacked up EF model to a proper EF model matching the new data structure.

Is this viable? Is it possible to use the EF interface, with LINQ without actually pointing it to a database?

I have managed to query the legacy systems by overriding the generated DbContext and exposing IQueryable properties which query the old systems. My big fight now is with actually updating the data.

If I am able to have EF track changes to entities, but not actually save those changes. I should be able to override the SaveChanges() method on the context to manually insert into various legacy tables.

I'm sort of at wits end with this issue at the moment.

UDPATE 4 Sept 2012: I've opted to use the EDMX file designer to build the data model and I generate the code by using T4. This enables me to then manually write mapping code to suit my needs. It also allows me to later perform a legacy data migration with relative ease.

Comment: Anything is possible, of course, but I'm pretty sure this approach is not feasible. Is there a reason you do not want to implement a back-end database and handle the data interop between legacy systems from there? That is a well-worn path to getting where you're trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your situation I'd setup the new DB server and link the legacy servers to it. Then create stored procedures to interface with EF for the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. This way your EF code remains separate from the legacy support messiness. As you decommission the legacy DB servers you can update your stored procedures accordingly. Once you have no more legacy DB servers you can either continue using your sprocs or do a refresh of your EF data connection to use the table schema directly.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework is to link entities to a data store without manual populates. 
Otherwise you're just using classes with linq.

If you mean you don't want a seperate data store like sql server, mongo etc etc, then just let your application create the database as an mdb file that gets bundled in your app_data file. That means you don't need a databsae server so to speak and the database is part of your app.

If on the other hand you want a different way to save to the database, you can create your own data adapters to behave however you like. The mongo .net entity framework component is an example of this.

Alternatively, using code only you can just use stored procedures to persist to the database which can be a bit verbose and annoying with EF, but could bridge the gap for you you and allow you to build a good architecture with a model you want that gets translated into the crappy one in your repositories.

Then when the new database is ready, you can just rework your repo's to use savechanges and you're done.

This will of course only work with the code only approach.